# Copy URL from browser address bar and pasting into form using html?

Tags: java, html, forms, mailto

I'm looking to create an online form that on the surface is very basic.

The goal is to create a mailto form with submit button that, upon submission with copy the **current** url with in the browser address bar and paste it into the mailto email window.

The form itself is straight forward:

```
form method="post" action="mailto:address@address.ca">
Report a broken link, please use the submit button below. The URL for the broken link will be included automatically.
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form
```

the simpler the better, html/java is preferred... suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you get the URL with javascript's `document.URL` and do whatever you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'>
</script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
  $(window).load(function(){
  var url = "mailto:address@address.ca?Subject=" + window.location;
  $('#mailtoLink').attr('href', url);
  window.alert($('#mailtoLink').attr('href')); // = url;
  });//]]>  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  Some Text <a id="mailtoLink" href="mailto:address@address.ca" name="mailtoLink">Send Mail</a>
</body>
</html>
```